# Keycloak multivalued attribute is not sent as array for some users

Tags: oauth-2.0, attributes, keycloak, multivalue

We are using KeyCloak as SSO directory for our application. We use OAuth 2.0 protocol.
We have defined one custom attribute in KeyCloak, and this attributed has "MultiValued" properties on.

Then, each user has multiple values entered as value1##value2##value3

For some users Keycloak correctly send the attribute in the ID token as an array of values, such as ["value1", "value2", "value3"]

But for some other users, the string is passed as it is entered "value1##value2##value3", which is not correct.

I'm struggling finding why these different behaviours occur.

Has anyone seen the same problem ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak uses ## as a delimiter internally, this is ok. Make sure you have marked the value as multivalued in the clients mapper.

After doing this i went from getting only the last element to getting all elements.